# How to have two versions of images for dark/light theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I want to have a light and dark theme but I also want the images to fit the theme. But how to do that? And is it more heavy at page load or it can load only one image depending on the selected theme, and lazily load the other if the user changes the theme?

Comment: It really depends on how you are implementing the dark/light mode feature. If you are using css only, you can use the image as a background image of a div and flip the value when the user changes the theme. If you are using a js based solution, update the image src value or the css of a div etc to change it. Your browser should only load the image when needed using either of the methods above. Post some code here so we can help better :) Check out the [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider improving yoour question :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `background-blend-mode` (CSS) can help you change the images take a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/)

This way you only need one version of the image and CSS is quite fast!

Or you could play around with [filters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)